# Is there a chance to omit 'next' part from RxJs 'subscribe'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, refactoring

I'm wondering if I can transform following piece of code to one without 'next' part from RxJS 'subscribe'. I'm not interested here to get any results from service. The only thing, which matters here is catching potential error to react properly.

```
    this.someService.getSomething(this.id)
      .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        // I don't need this part at all
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
           // doing sth important
        }
      });
```

Is there a chance to do something with that in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something with [catch / catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-error-handling)

```
this.someService.getSomething(this.id)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    catchError(
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          // doing sth important
        }
      })
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a [PartialObserver](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L82) to subscribe and define or omit `next`, `error` and `complete`:

```js
source.subscribe({ error: (e: any) => console.error(e) })
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered above, you can use `catchError` operator. But, if you need to subscribe anyway, you may also use the subscribe method like this `this.someService.getSomething(this.id).subscribe(null, (error) => {..})`